# How do I force re-execution of a resolve function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angularjs ui-router setup that uses a resolve to load data from my server. I also get notifications through a websocket that the data is now stale (it's a rare configuration-change event but it happens nonetheless)

How do I force a re-execution of the associated resolve function to make sure my consumers get a fresh version of the data ?

Comment: Why you don't move your functions in resolve of router to a service and call it again anytime you get notification from socket

Comment: because I would like to avoid having to restructure my entire app to deal with a rarely-occuring corner-case that nonetheless happens ?